# How can I get Android to resolve XML resources?

Tags: android, xml

I'm doing Example 3 on the [Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html) on developer.android.com.

It's time to run my code, but I can't even compile, because I have errors on lines that call `R.layout.*something*` or `R.string.*something*`. Every error is of the type...

"*something* cannot be resolved or is not a field."

...which signals to me that maybe I named something wrong or forgot to name it in the XML. So I check my XML files and do a little cleanup. Everything seems to be normal. No red Xs.

I go back to the class, where I see what looks odd to me. In two separate lines that call to two separate elements in the same layout file, one yields an error and one doesn't:

```
mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title); // no error
mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body); // error: "body cannot be resolved or is not a field"
```

[image: Two lines calling to the same XML file; one gives an error.]

Again, Eclipse isn't showing me any errors on the XML file:

[image: I don't see any glaring errors in my XML.]

What might I have done wrong that some of the resources are resolving in the code and some aren't? Is this something Eclipse can sort out, similar to **Project -> Clean...**?

If it makes any difference, I picked Android 2.1 as a build target. And I **am** importing android.R.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does **Project -> Clean...** do anything at all? Usually when I get errors with the generated R file, a Clean and Build will resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of importing `android.R` try importing `com.android.demo.notepad3.R`

Comment: Thanks. It's running now. What's happening here? The R file is only generating based on what's in the package namespace? Funny, because Eclipse automatically inserted that `import android.R` when I did Cmd-Shift-O. What other packages might I import this way?

Comment: @parisminton I've only experienced the issue with the `R` class myself.  It happened to me when the class I was working on was in a sub-package of the default package for the application.  Eclipse seemed to get confused with the organise imports.

Answer (score 2):

try removing the R import lines altogether